# Adding the logg Mode in JBOSS 6.4

Tags: jboss, openshift

I wanted to change the jboss config file  so that all logging (application logs and server log) is written to the console when it starts. The current config file (standalone.xml) only makes SERVER logs visible on console , we cannot see Application log.
what should i add to the code to make application logs also visible on console.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Thanks

Comment: What environment are you running in? By default logs are written to the console and there is no `LOG_ROOT` environment variable defined.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins , so I am working on Openshift. So currently we have Jboss 6.4 running and on the openshift , we can see the logs just in log terminal but we wanted to see all the logs on Console terminal. 
We dnt want to change the path but want to switch the mode of log to console terminal. 
Thank you

Comment: Hello,
here is the Elaborate version of my task : 

The current standalone.yaml file has config setting to display only Server logs to the Openshift console. we don't see any application logs on the console at the moment. so we wanted to change the config file (standalone.yaml) so both the server logs and applications logs should be visible to Console Logs in Openshift.


would be really greatfull, if you can help.
Thank you

Comment: By default that should be happening. Do you have a logging configuration file in your deployment?

Comment: Actually not. no other file for the deployment.

instead of the above file, does it make sense to add another handler for application log ?
like this ?
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/> (for server.logs)
 <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir

Comment: You'd need to add a console handler as well if you want to see the logs on the console.